# Laplace transform of $\frac{f(t)}{1-e^{-at}}$

Tags: laplace-transform

I would like to know if there is a way to calculate the Laplace transform for a given $f(t)$:

$$\dfrac{f(t)}{1-e^{-at}}$$

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Integral_representations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $a>0$, get

$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\infty} dt \frac{f(t)}{1-e^{-a t}} e^{-s t} &=\int_0^{\infty} dt\, f(t) \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} e^{-(s + a k)t} \\ &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \hat{f}(s+k a)  \end{align}$$

where we reversed the order of summation and integration, and

$$\hat{f}(s) = \int_0^{\infty} dt \,f(t) e^{-s t}$$

Comment: Thanks!really appreciated.

Comment: Why rollback? Please note that all of the contents in SE are serving for public and not only for the OP! In this question, it should have somebody expect you should also consider the case of $a<0$ , although the OP may not. So please be cooperate!

Comment: @doraemonpaul: then make a note of it in a separate answer.  I consider my answers to be representative of what I contributed.  I felt like you were putting words in my mouth that I did not say.  I am consistent with this in how I vote edits as well.  If you have a problem with this, please take it up with a moderator.